# Conditional Type in Typescript based on another Type

Tags: typescript

I'm having issues with conditional types.

I require that when `filter[triggerType]` on `AutomationParams` changes, `filter[triggerId]` values also update to the proper kind.

For instance, when `filter[triggerType]` equals `corn`, the alternatives for `filter[triggerId]` are limited to being of the `CronTriggerId` type.

```
 type TriggerType = 'event' | 'cron' | 'scheduled';

 type EventTriggerId = 'extendStayRequired' | 'reservationAccessChanged'

 type CronTriggerId = 'reservationsCron';
 
 type ScheduledTriggerId = 'reservationCheckedIn';


 type TriggerId<T> = T extends 'event'
  ? EventTriggerId
  : T extends 'cron'
  ? CronTriggerId
  : T extends 'scheduled'
  ? ScheduledTriggerId
  : never;

 type AutomationParams = {
  'filter[triggerType]': TriggerType;
  'filter[triggerId]': TriggerId<TriggerType>;
};

const obj: AutomationParams = {
  'filter[triggerType]': 'cron',
  'filter[triggerId]': 'extendStayRequired',
};
```

Additionally, this is the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=14#code/AQFwngDgpsAqBOBLA5sq9aRgXmAcigDcoA7EPYAH3wGN4B7Ei6vAZxoAsoATAVwBseeANwBYAFATQWYAFFiZBCjTwAkt2C4CADxCluAZRABDMACUoAR16J4Qqvjut0hYyESMAgjRpRWrAGEOYxI0bjwpcGhgAIYSJVR0dU1HPxc3DxJAuJFImQNOHgEeBJVkrSd090YgqBoAax5VJjFJcWlo0qTuAB5YAD4U2GAoXX1WfCJScilgAH45BRAutW5ZgC44EbGSbgm8OkYI9vmYuJX1Da3RvV399i4+QXDZhYLH4u4LtZPNkin4K08tFPLwQPQALYZRgABWM8GMEImuAA3rM8AAzRD8PTwADaICQiQwWAAunhNitMNBWsB8FicegCUSytxyZSWd0+pySdB+q0AL5A8Q0RisEDAegAIwAVptQeCodUSHCEUiUmiTpjsbjmcp0NSoOz8A8is88AAadEM3WE-WrY06W6GEzmKw2OzhK3iIUSCSirL0QQAOn49GQAAppTKAJRAA).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to rewrite `TriggerId` to just be a simple lookup map.

```
type TriggerMap = {
  event: EventTriggerId
  cron: CronTriggerId
  scheduled: ScheduledTriggerId
}
```

`AutomationParams` can now be calculated to be a union of all valid combinations.

```
type AutomationParams = {
  [K in keyof TriggerMap]: {
    'filter[triggerType]': K;
    'filter[triggerId]': TriggerMap[K];
  }
}[keyof TriggerMap]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=14#code/AQFwngDgpsAqBOBLA5sq9aRgXmAcigDcoA7EPYAH3wGN4B7Ei6vAZxoAsoATAVwBseeANwBYAFATQWYAFFiZBCjTwAkt2C4CADxCluAZRABDMACUoAR16J4Qqvjut0hYyESMAgjRpRWrAGEOYxI0bjwpcGhgAIYSJVR0dU1HPxc3DxJAuJFImQNOHgEeBJVkrSd090YgqBoAax5VJjFJcSiYUvQAWWMIFIBvKWAiUhAALjkFEC61bmG6RknYxln1YfYuPkFuSYKt4u41%20fEAXwkJDuBPXhB6AFsMxgAFY3hje9ZB4YBtAGlgIgSMBGmB6AAzOBIRLwXoQAC6kyG4mAqPw4MQ-D08B%20IGhKkw0HheEmf1aaPRmOxuPxSW4xMmszh-3h5OA5zOP1BEKhyh6fXhF3ENEYrBAwHoACMAFaTG53R7VEivd6fb4oylY9A0vkYLAM-CbIo7PAAGmGeAxWpxeN16gNOj0JEMJnMVhsdnC5rOrQkIqy9EEADp%20PRkAAKKXSgCUQA)

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. But imagine we have another type on `AutomationParams` like sort: string;.` How should I add it?

Comment: @SerajVahdati - you can put it just beneath the other two properties.

Answer (score 0):

**AutomationParams should itself be a union :**

```
 type EventTriggerId = 'extendStayRequired' | 'reservationAccessChanged'
 type CronTriggerId = 'reservationsCron';
 type ScheduledTriggerId = 'reservationCheckedIn';


 type AutomationParams = {
  'filter[triggerType]': 'event';
  'filter[triggerId]': EventTriggerId;
} | {
  'filter[triggerType]': 'cron';
  'filter[triggerId]': CronTriggerId;
} | {
  'filter[triggerType]': 'scheduled';
  'filter[triggerId]': ScheduledTriggerId;
};

const obj: AutomationParams = {
  'filter[triggerType]': 'scheduled',
  'filter[triggerId]': 'reservationCheckedIn',
};

console.log(obj)
```

**Or use mapping interface :**

```
 type TriggerType = 'event' | 'cron' | 'scheduled';
 
 type EventTriggerId = 'extendStayRequired' | 'reservationAccessChanged'
 type CronTriggerId = 'reservationsCron';
 type ScheduledTriggerId = 'reservationCheckedIn';


export interface AutomationParams<T extends TriggerType> {
    'filter[triggerType]': T
    'filter[triggerId]': TriggerId[T]
}
type TriggerId ={
    'event': EventTriggerId,
    'cron': CronTriggerId,
    'scheduled': ScheduledTriggerId

}

const obj: AutomationParams<'event'> = {
  'filter[triggerType]': 'event',
  'filter[triggerId]': 'extendStayRequired',
};

console.log(obj)
```

**You could also do it with conditional types:**

```
type TriggerType = 'event' | 'cron' | 'scheduled';

 type EventTriggerId = 'extendStayRequired' | 'reservationAccessChanged'

 type CronTriggerId = 'reservationsCron';
 
 type ScheduledTriggerId = 'reservationCheckedIn';


 type TriggerId<T> = T extends 'event'
  ? EventTriggerId
  : T extends 'cron'
  ? CronTriggerId
  : T extends 'scheduled'
  ? ScheduledTriggerId
  : never;

 type AutomationParams<T extends TriggerType> = {
  'filter[triggerType]': T;
  'filter[triggerId]': TriggerId<T>;
};

const obj: AutomationParams<'cron'> = {
  'filter[triggerType]': 'cron',
  'filter[triggerId]': 'reservationsCron',
};
```